# Controlling TRIAC with PWM from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, mains, triac, dimmer

I am looking to control a mains heater with a microcontroller. It seems like most solutions use an optocoupler to signal the microcontroller at a zero crossing and another optocoupler to trigger the gate of the TRIAC after a set amount of time depending on the target phase angle. I'm hoping to try a different design that uses the PWM duty cycle directly to control this timing, more similar to how a manual dimmer circuit works. A normal dimmer circuit looks like this:

[image]

After each zero-crossing, the capacitor charges up at a given speed based on the potentiometer. Then once it reaches the DIAC's breakover voltage, it dumps the charge into the TRIAC's gate, opening the channel until the next zero-crossing. My design is this:

[image]

In this case, the charge rate of C2 is controlled by the duty cycle of the PWM signal instead of the potentiometer. The only difference in my case is that because the phototransistor in the optocoupler is only meant to operate in one direction, the C2 has to be charged from C1, which is always charged to +170V instead of the AC mains sine wave. This should be fine though, as TRIACs are abled to be triggered with any combination of MT2 and Gate relative to MT1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC

Is there anything wrong with this design? Why do I not see anything like this out there given its simplicity, similarity to the manual dimmer circuit, and lack of overhead on the part of the microcontroller? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I know the voltage rating of the PC817D is too low for my application. I just put together the LTSpice circuit for demonstration purposes. I don't even have a model for the TRIAC.

Comment: Perhaps because you can just get TRIAC-output optocouplers?

Comment: @Hearth Do you mean use a TRIAC-output optocoupler with my current design so I can get rid of D1/C1 and have a closer circuit to the manual dimmer? I considered that, but the TRIAC-output optocouplers still have the holding current characteristic, so the first pulse from the microcontroller during the half cycle will trigger the optocoupler, and it would stay open for the full half cycle.

Comment: That's inherent to how a triac works. You can't turn them off except by waiting for the next zero-crossing.

Comment: @Hearth I understand, that's ultimately why I can't use a TRIAC-output optocoupler for this implementation. In the case where TRIAC-output optocouplers are used, they still use the microcontroller to time a single pulse after a zero-crossing, which is what I'm trying to avoid with this design.

Comment: You realize your overall circuit here will have the exact same thing, right? I don't see the point of all this additional circuitry. You still can't turn the triac off.

Comment: I realize the TRIAC is still controlled by Phase Angle Control (PAC). This circuit allows the microcontroller to control the PAC angle directly from the PWM duty cycle. Other circuits do not control the phase angle with PWM. They control it using feedback from mains to detect zero-crossings and an internal timer to deliver a single pulse. The manual dimmers use a variable charging time of a capacitor to do this timing, using a potentiometer to vary the time. My circuit uses this manual dimmer capacitor charge time approach, but with PWM controlling the charge time, rather than a potentiometer.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing now, but why? Why not do it the normal way, since you have a microcontroller that's capable of doing the appropriate timing anyway?

Comment: @Hearth For one, I want to minimize the overhead on the microcontroller. It's probably well within its capabilities, but I'd rather have a passive approach if possible. Also, this seems simpler to me. I need to use the DIAC, the 2 capacitors, and the diode. But if I use the timing method, I will need an auxiliary circuit with a full-bridge rectifier, another optocoupler, etc. Can you see any reason my circuit won't work?